# How to include givenName and surname in SAML metadata so that it is included, optionally

Tags: java, saml, onelogin

We have an IDP and like for our clients to include first and last name. Do we need to specify that in our metadata? We use the Java open source kit.

I presume we need to add this to the metadata:

```
<saml:AttributeStatement>
            <saml:Attribute Name="EmailAddress" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
                <saml:AttributeValue>first_last@example.com</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="FirstName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
                <saml:AttributeValue>First</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="LastName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
                <saml:AttributeValue>Last</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
</saml:AttributeStatement>
```

But how do you do that when we use keys to create the metadata, such as

```
 samlData.put("onelogin.saml2.sp.single_logout_service.binding", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect");
```

Comment: I.E. how does one represent SAML attributes with the Onelogin keys?

Comment: I think we have an SP, not an  IDP